# Overlapping jQuery pluggin on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote my own jQuery pluggin, but I want to allow users to over-write the existing settings. Currently if you try to do this, the browsers runs *two* instances of the jQuery pluggin on the single element. Yeah... I don't know how to test for this, or show it in console, or even how to approach this problem.

Thanks ahead of time for your help!!

Here is a working *example* of the problem: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4zyqn5pm/2/)

```
// my innovative jquery pluggin!
$.fn.blink = function(options) {

    // basic setup
    var defaults = {blinkInterval: 3000}
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    var $box = $(this),
        delay = settings.blinkInterval;

    // hide box, then show after half the time has passed
    function blinkFunction(){
        $box.hide();
        setTimeout(function(){$box.show();}, delay/2)
    }

    // start blinking, set interval of full time provided
    setInterval(blinkFunction, delay);
};

// now use my pluggin!
$('#box').blink({blinkInterval:2000}); // blink every two seconds
$('#box').blink({blinkInterval:3000}); // blink every three seconds

// the goal is for this 3 second instance to over-write the 2 second one, because it was called later on. But unfortunately, right now it blinks every 2 seconds AND every 3 seconds!!! Sometimes they line up, and sometimes they don't... :(
```

Comment: It needs to be used with 2 different elements - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4zyqn5pm/4/

Comment: Clear the timeouts and intervals - check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/4zyqn5pm/5/

Comment: updated - https://jsfiddle.net/4zyqn5pm/6/

Comment: Clearing the timeouts works for this example, but this is just an example to demonstrate the over-lapping issue. 


I was more looking for a way to over-write the {settings} object, and re-initiate the pluggin with the new settings. I assumed there was a standardized way to do that and I have not yet discovered it, but maybe there isn't...

Comment: ooh okay..gotcha. That should be possible if you could expose an update kind of method. Will try that out!

Comment: But in any case, you gotta update the setInterval and setTimeOut...I dont think there is any other go...

Answer (score 0):

Update the intervals and timeout assigned for that particular element:

```js
var $blink_timeout = [],
  $blink_interval = [];
// my innovative jquery pluggin!
$.fn.blink = function(options) {
  // basic setup
  var defaults = {
    blinkInterval: 3000
  }
  var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
  var $box = $(this),
    delay = settings.blinkInterval,
    $id = $(this).attr("id");

  //alert($id);
  clearTimeouts();

  // hide box, then show after half the time has passed
  function blinkFunction() {
    $box.hide();
    $blink_timeout[$id] = setTimeout(function() {
      $box.show();
    }, delay / 2)
  };

  // start blinking, set interval of full time provided
  $blink_interval[$id] = setInterval(blinkFunction, delay);

  function clearTimeouts() {
    //clearTimeouts
    clearTimeout($blink_timeout[$id]);
    clearInterval($blink_interval[$id]);
  };
};

// now use my pluggin!
$('#box').blink({
  blinkInterval: 2000
}); // blink every two seconds
$('#box').blink({
  blinkInterval: 5000
}); // blink every three seconds
$('#box2').blink({
  blinkInterval: 2000
});

// the goal is for this 3 second instance to over-write the 2 second one, because it was called later on. But unfortunately, right now it blinks every 2 seconds AND every 3 seconds!!! Sometimes they line up, and sometimes they don't... :(
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
 
}

#box2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Watch me blink!</p>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```